# Avoid locked screen from lighting up on notifications?

Tags: notifications

When my phone is locked (i.e. screen is black), it lights up on whenever some app generates a notification.

Can I avoid this? When locked, I don't want the screen to light up or show any visual indication that there is a notification. When I manually turn on the phone, I'll notice the notification icons at the top myself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can stop background services by Settings > Applications > Background Tasks. Or simply turn on battery saver mode that stop all background tasks. Whenever you're ready to receive notification, revert it back. I think there's no better solution for this problem right now.

Comment: Hmmm thanks, but disabling background tasks will no longer receive notifications *at all*? (until I manually re-enable it?)

Comment: Yes it's. I can't find any other way @Huckleberry

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Windows 10 Mobile do this:

All Settings > System > Notifications & Actions

Under 'Notifications' turn 'Show notifications in action center when my phone is locked' to off.

This may work.